# Why killing other humans in the Walking Dead?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

In season 3 of the *Walking Dead* television series, what is the problem with the Governor? Why is he killing other humans?

For God's sake, it's the Apocalypse, 95% of the world is dead, all the technology has been destroyed. Everyone is sad because of losing many loved ones and still - their exists this one man *Governor* who is killing other humans. But why?

Comment: Actually this part was the reason I stopped watching the series.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In one of the first episodes introducing the character of the Governor, we see him and his men murder a team of soldiers heavily armed, to rid them of their weapons.
If he did not had killed them, but had instead incorporated them to its little community, with their equipment, training, and experience as a unified team, the soldiers might have been strong enough to take over the control of the organization of the Governor's community.
This is something that the Governor could not bear : the power he has over the community is all he wants.

That's how I started to think about this character after watching the movie "The Postman" (that I actually liked), and comparing him to the bad guy, "General Bethlehem".
The General shares some aspects with the Governor : he explains he was a kind of loser before the apocalypse, but he has power in the new order of the world and therefore enjoys it a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I think Carl's shooting of Jody as Jody was surrendering in the season 3 finale was meant to parallel and illustrate how The Governor became the way he was. A person in those circumstances starts to think that shooting is always the safest option, whereas not shooting can lead to tragedy later. Eventually preemptive killing becomes second nature. (I know Jody was acting suspiciously, but Herschel said Carl shot him in cold blood, and Herschel was right there.)

Answer (score 1):

The Governor stamps out anything he perceives as a threat to his position and community. He has a vision for survival and expects all others to follow it.